# Parallel algorithm for counting the number of closed loops on a flat 2D matrix of non negative integers

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

I broke my head trying to understand how to implement a parallel algorithm for finding closed loops on a 2D matrix. The contours are given as a determined single positive integer on the matrix, and there will be no open contours on the matrix. Also: Contours do not intersect and touch each other!
I tried to implement the following: change the contour number to negative  in one thread until an already negated point appears. However, terrible racing conditions appear, and so there appears serializing memory access through atomic operations. Thus all the benefits of using a parallel architecture are lost.
And of course, it would be nice for each thread to locally process its own region (for example, only the Moore neighborhood or von Neumann), but I don't have an idea how to do this without atomic operations.
Thanks in advance!
Here is an example (There are three circles of 7 and so answer is 3):

[image]

Comment: Can the loops touch each other?

Comment: I suppose this case can be considered an intersection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering, your loops cannot touch each other:

Declare atomic (integer?) variable result with initial value of 0.

For each row (or column, does't matter) do this routine in parallel:

Find group of integers indicing a loop (7 in your case) - the group may contain only a single digit, cannot have any 0 inside of it, but has to have 0 on the left and on the right, also, there can be multiple groups, but cannot be connected to another group (this means, there is at least 1x 0 between groups). Let's say you have this row:

```
Indexes: | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
Numbers: | 0 | 7 | 0 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 0 | 0 |
```

There are 2 gorups on this line:

Group1: from=1, to=1 (indexes)

Group2: from=3, to=5

if there is number indicing loop (7) at from-1 and at to+1 in the next row (or column), add 1 to result atomically (only if next row/column exists) - for each group that satisfies this condition.